# Increasing data transfer speed on simple TCP client/socket

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, stream

I have a homework assignment to create a simple data transfer mechanism with a client/server TCP socket pair by redirecting standard I/O. I actually have it working, but when I try to transfer large files (say ~5g) the speed slows down dramatically. I am using BufferedInputStream and BufferedOutputStream, and I think that perhaps there is some optimization I can make there. The code for my server is:

```
private static final int BUF_SIZE = 2047;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
   /*
    * Attempt to parse command line arguments.
    * @require args[0] is an int
    */
   int port = 0;
   try {
       port = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
   } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
       System.err.println("Port must be an integer in range 0 - 65535.");
       System.exit(-1);
   }

   /*
    * Bind server socket to specified port number and wait for request.
    * @require port >= 0 && port <= 65535
    */
   ServerSocket welcomeSocket = null;
   welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
   System.out.println("Now listening on port: " + port);

    /*
     * Accept connection from client socket.
     */
    Socket connectionSocket = null;
    connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();
    System.out.println("Client made connection");

    BufferedInputStream input;
    BufferedOutputStream output;
    if(System.in.available() > 0) {
        input = new BufferedInputStream(System.in, BUF_SIZE);
        output = new BufferedOutputStream(
                connectionSocket.getOutputStream(), BUF_SIZE);
    } else {
        input = new BufferedInputStream(
                connectionSocket.getInputStream(), BUF_SIZE);
        output = new BufferedOutputStream(System.out, BUF_SIZE);
    }

    int place;
    while((place = input.read()) != -1)
        output.write(place);

    input.close();
    output.close();
    welcomeSocket.close();
    connectionSocket.close();
}
```

The client code is essentially the same. I have tried using different buffer sizes, including the default (by not specifying a buffer size), but they are all running at approximately the same speed. Any pointers on how I can increase my performance?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Does the transfer actually slow down with large files, or is the speed just more noticeable when you transfer them? You may be hitting the limit of your hardware -- 5 GB files generally don't transfer very fast on any network.

Comment: That's a good question that I didn't consider. Is there a command when using cmd to determine actual speed of transfer?

Comment: I think that *but they are all running at approximately the same speed* is telling.  Can you give us some idea of relative transfer speeds and the slowdown you're getting?  It's a little more complicated than "why does it slow down for big files?" It's likely not your code at the root of the slowdown.

Comment: @A D Also, the stream buffer size probably has less impact when you're reading and writing bytewise.

Comment: @keith.layne It takes approximately 12 minutes to transfer the 5g file and approximately 30 seconds to transfer a 700MB file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
while((place = input.read()) != -1)
```

You're reading one byte at a time from the buffer. The overhead of calling this method millions of times is rather large.

I would suggest reading more than one byte into a buffer with the other version (and writing the same way):

```
public int read(byte[] b,
            int off,
            int len)
```

Example:

```
byte[] myBuffer = new byte[BUF_SIZE];
while((place = input.read(myBuffer, 0, BUF_SIZE)) != 1)
    output.write(myBuffer, 0, place);
```

Comment: @Brendan There's still the overhead of a function call per byte, right?  I would think that even though it's buffered, an array copy is way cheaper.

Comment: Thank you so much for the example! Changing it to use this read() instead actually cut down on the time dramatically. It took me about 45 seconds to transfer the 5g file.

Comment: @Brendan - Erm, no? Once that buffer is full (which is milliseconds since it's only a couple K) he's performing a read for 1 byte. The underlying buffer is then filled back to capacity with ... one byte. Millions and millions of times, one byte at a time.

Comment: Not to brag or anything but I definitely mentioned the bytewise read/writes in a comment before either answer was posted.  I'm kind of a big deal around here. :)

Comment: @Keith - If it makes you feel any better, I was busy posting the answer at the time ;)

Comment: @Brian I know, but you're not supposed to tell anyone that. :) I was so busy writing an irrelevant comment that I barely noticed it.

Comment: @Brian Roach - Once the buffer is empty, the BufferedInputStream will request another block of data (internally doing what you suggest). Otherwise, it would be completely useless. I suspect you're right about the function call overhead though.

Comment: @Brendan - the problem is, it would never *be* empty. The JavaDoc says: *As bytes from the stream are read or skipped, the internal buffer is refilled as necessary from the contained input stream*. The underlying buffer doesn't wait to be drained completely before refilling from the socket. Thus it actually exasperates the problem because there's even more calls going on behind the scenes.

Comment: @Brian Roach - "As bytes from the stream are read or skipped, the internal buffer is refilled as necessary from the contained input stream, **many bytes at a time**": http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedInputStream.html

Comment: @Breandan - Yes, *to the max size of the underlying buffer* which is passed to the `BufferedInputStream` constructor. So if it's full and you read 20 bytes, it'll refill with 20 bytes. Read 1000 bytes, it refills with 1000 bytes. Read *one* byte and ...

Comment: @Brian Roach - I don't see where you're getting this from. It says "as necessary", which to me means, "when it runs out of data". If it worked how you're suggesting, it would be **completely worthless**.

Comment: And proof, check out the source for OpenJDK's BufferedInputStream: http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/io/BufferedInputStream.java.html Specifically `if(pos > count)  { fill(); ...`. It's very explicit: It refills the buffer when it runs out.

Comment: @Keith - I figured I should read the source :) At least looking at the JDK7 source you're actually right in your initial assumption - it does not refill the underlying buffer until it's empty. I think the javadoc is slightly misleading there, but I'm man enough to admit when I'm wrong. (Edit: LOL, which apparently, you were doing the same)

Answer (score 3):

you are reading and sending a byte at a time which is not efficient, you should read blocks of data (idle size would be the disk hardware buffer size).
of course, the disk should be your bottle neck here it takes time to read 5G form disk.

Comment: Your answer is correct on why it was so slow ... except for the part at the end. Provided the machine isn't hammering the disk doing something else, I guarantee you the disk is faster than the network (Unless it's a floppy drive) ;) Even gigabit ethernet isn't going to be faster than a SATA drive.

Comment: As I mentioned in comments on the other answer, BufferedInputStreams already do this. I think the problem is the overhead of a function call, not the physicals reads/writes.

Comment: you probably right, although large file might be fragmented across the file system and require a large access time (also accessing the file node structures...etc).